# Aws Auto Scaling with Bamboo as a CICD Tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, bamboo, autoscaling

We have setup Aws Auto Scaling for ec2 Instances based on CPU utilization.

My concern is how can we define CICD flow for newly created instances if we are using Bamboo as a CICD Tool so that whatever deployment done on new instances will stay even after that instance gets terminated.

Anybody here have an idea how generally CICD done with AWS ASG and Bamboo CICD tool?

Thanks

Comment: If I understood the question correctly then, you want to have a code deployed on new instance created via AWS autoscaling happened based on CPU utilization. To load the latest code base you can either use the AMI with lastest code in launch configuration (less recommended since AMI new to upgrade frequently with latest code) or second is have a script to do the deployment via user data in AWS.

Comment: Thank you for your thought but It is not about latest code or anything, I would like to know how I can integrate Bamboo server with AWS ASG, so that Bamboo can deploy automatically on newly created instances and in case of scale in I should noy worry about an artifacts which are deployed on that Instances

Comment: Bamboo is nothing but a deployment tool which would be running deployment scripts behind the scenes, so there is no direct/automatic integration between bamboo and AWS ASG. but to implement that you can use your deployment script and call it from ec2 user data to deploy the artifacts. refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: That make sense. So how should I design my CICD flow from end to end... Any suggestions?